# How do I troubleshoot an image pull backoff from a Gitlab registry?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, gitlab

I have recently starting working on the system admin side of a running k8s cluster, there is an operator that handles helm releases for generating web instances.

I am attempting to update this operator by first generating a new image via CI/CD on GitLab, and then updating the deployment to pull this new image. The previous image can be pulled fine on various k8s nodes, however the new node cannot be found.

I have tried ssh'ing to the nodes, using the docker login credentials from the relevant GitLab token and pulling this image. Again, I can pull previous images from the same registry, but not the image I have created. I have checked and tried various spellings (and going forward I purely use the "copy" button on the GitLab container registry) but the image still cannot be found.

What is the best approaches for troubleshooting this?

```
The exact error output from the events log of kubectl describe pod is: 

    Events:
          Type    Reason   Age                   From     Message
          ----    ------   ----                  ----     -------
          Normal  BackOff  4m8s (x290 over 73m)  kubelet  Back-off pulling image "reg.dafni.rl.ac.uk/dafni/nivs/operator/20230801:latest"
```

**Update**

Since this question was posted, I have been able to pull the image locally and push it back to the repository with a different name. Now the kubernetes cluster nodes are able to pull the newer image, but the older image is not.

I also attempted to use a tool called [container-diff](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/container-diff) to inspect the images locally. Despite being able to pull the image, the container diff tool complains about there being no manifest for the problematic images.

```
ERRO[0004] error retrieving image reg.dafni.rl.ac.uk/dafni/nivs/operator/20230801: MANIFEST_UNKNOWN: OCI manifest found, but accept header does not support OCI manifests
```

Comment: Can you give us the exact error output the pod is giving, maybe using `kubectl describe pod <pod_in_imagepullbackoff_state>`. The useful lines are located near the bottom, in the events section

Comment: I've updated the question to include the events log. I get a similar response when logging into the node and manually pulling the image with the gitlab credentials. 

However, on the nodes of our new cluster machine I was able to pull down exactly this image.